# Find period of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Consider $f(x) = \ln(\sin x)$ . First of all , Is $f(x)$ a periodic function ? And if it is periodic what is the period ?

My try : For finding period , this equation is obvious : $\ln(\sin x) = \ln(\sin (x+T))$ but I can't solve it .

Comment: Note that for $x$ such that $\sin x\leq 0$ the function is not even defined,and what problems do you have with the equation it seems pretty easy to solve.

Comment: The period should be between (o, $\frac{\pi}{2}$].

Comment: @Iti Shree The wolfram alpha says it isn't perodic function .

Comment: @kingW3 Thank you for hint . I got $\sin x = \sin(x+T)$ equation . Therefore $T = 2\pi$ but wolfram alpha shows it as a non-periodic function .

Comment: @S.H.W I'm unaware of what wolfram alpha is, can you explain? BTW It can't be negative definitively since it's logarithm function.

Comment: @ItiShree See : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period+ln(sin(x))

Comment: I don't see why the website says it's not periodic since the graph is repeating after certain interval.

Comment: @S.H.W Wolfram alpha algorithm is pretty confusing it could be using some complex valued function and $\ln$ is multivalued so it looks like it isn't periodic but take a look at [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(sin(x))%3Dln(sin(x%2B2pi))) or [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Re(ln(sin(x)))%3DRe(ln(sin(x%2B2pi))))

Comment: @kingW3 So it is a periodic function undoubtedly . Are you sure ?

Comment: @S.H.W Yep sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln$ is a strictly increasing function thus injective where defined.

So $\ln(\sin x)$ has same period than $\sin$ which is $T=2\pi$.

The domain of definition is $D=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb Z}]0,\pi[+kT$

---

To answer your question in comment : when using $x$ we generally refer to the real valued function. Wolfram-alpha in this case draw the complex-valued one.

But even though, it has the same period assuming we choose a proper determination $\operatorname{Ln}$ of the logarithm that agrees with $x\in\mathbb R$ (a cut at $\Im(x)>0$ for instance).

If $x\in]0,\pi[$ then $\operatorname{Ln}(\sin(x))=\ln(\sin(x))$

If $x\in]\pi,2\pi[$ then $\operatorname{Ln}(\sin(x))=\operatorname{Ln}(-1)+\ln(|\sin(x)|)=i\pi+\ln(\sin(x-\pi))$

On each of the intervals, the function is $2\pi$ periodic, so overall it is too.
Only the domain of definition changes to $D=\mathbb R\setminus\pi\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Can you explain why this happens : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period+ln(sin(x))

Comment: Do we have to tell logicians that wolframalpha is the new oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

That function is periodic. In general, if you have a function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so that $g(x)$ is periodic with period $p$, the function $f(g(x))$ will also be periodic with period $p$, because the argument of $f(x)$ is $g(x)$, and since the argument is repeating itself, the output will repeat itself.

Comment: See : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period+ln(sin(x))

Comment: Just because wolfram alpha says a function is not periodic doesn't mean it isn't periodic. By looking at a graph, one can clearly see that the function repeats itself. It's definitely periodic, unless some convention does not allow functions that repeatedly take on undefined values to be periodic.

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer that's exactly what I want to says, sometimes websites can be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. Perhaps it is because of the undefined values in each period that messed Wolfram Alpha up.